# Python webbrowser module works on Windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I got the foundation and ideas for this online. It works great when I run it in Windows 10 but not Ubuntu 16.04. On Ubuntu it mistakes the URL for a file and gives me a file not found error. Is this a user coding error, a Ubuntu problem, or a Python problem?

To be a bit more specific it is a gvfs-open error.

```
import webbrowser

new = 2

choice = raw_input('Type site name:\n> ')
site = choice
url1 = 'www..com'

url = url1[:4] + site + url1[4:]

webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
```

Here are the results.

`$ gvfs-open: www.google.com: error opening location: error when getting information for file '/home/username/Documents/www.google.com: no such file or directory`

Comment: did you print the value of `url` and then copy/paste into a browser to confirm nothing is changed? Could it be something about `\r\n` VS `\n` Windows VS Linux line-endings? Good luck.

Comment: Printing url produces identical results from both OSs. Thanks for the suggestion. It never occurred to me to use print as a testing tool.

Comment: The above code works for me on Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7, tested with 'google' as the site name. Can you post the stack trace you are getting when it throws an error?

Comment: Here are the results. $ gvfs-open: www.google.com: error opening location: error when getting information for file '/home/username/Documents/www.google.com: no such file or directory'

Comment: `www.google.com` is not a complete URL. Add a scheme at the beginning, like `https://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

I took Klaus D. advice and added `http://`. Now it works on both OSs.
Thank you!

```
import webbrowser

new = 2
choice = raw_input('Type site name:\n> ')
site = choice
url1 = 'www..com'
url = 'http://' + url1[:4] + site + url1[4:]

webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
```